# Bluetooth Headphones connect but there isn't any sound. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have connected a pair BoseQC35 Bluetooth headphones to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. In hardware I have selected the headphones as output.

I get sound from the headphones when I run `speaker-test` and when I receive system notifications.

However, sound from apps like Chrome and Spotify is NOT directed through the headphones.

Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: System sounds volume level and application volume level can be two different controls. Check both settings.

Comment: Does running `lsb_release -cs` in the terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T) produce `bionic`? If not, what does it say?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.20? Do you mean 18.04?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same thing happen to me. I went to: **Settings** -> **Sound** and selected an output different than the BlueTooth, then selected the BlueTooth output and sound started working. After doing this once, I have not had the problem since.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04, like Jean David [says](https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6):

Check the current `bluez` version in your system with the following command:

```
dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
```

If it is `5.48-0ubuntu0ppa`, add the following repository to get the last version of `bluez` (5.50 as of June 8/2018):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
sudo apt-get update
```

Then update to `bluez` 5.50 via:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

It works for me.

Comment: Also helped me. On `5.48*` there was neither sound nor audio device, on `5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1` the sound magically appeared! And in Sound Settings Mate tray applet, my headset device appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try the a2dp.py script found here:

https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae

I cannot explain what the problem is, but can tell that
1) pairing my bluetooth PC-dongle and then
2) running this script

makes a connection that works, 
at least for sound (e.g. playing mp3's in VLC, or Youtube video).

*Note: does not work perfectly, you might need to retry at least twice.   (Ubuntu 16.04.x)*