# Playing via Bluetooth

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

Playing via Bluetooth is quite simple most of the time.  Go to the "Bluetooth settings" and select the device to send the music to.

However, currently I am in the following situation (also after reboot):

I am connected to the speakers which I test successfully in "Settings, Sound" (Front left and right). But when I play some music via the Firefox browser, the sound is still on my laptop and not the external device.

How can I use the external device for audio?

Comment: this seems to be the same question with the same answer as this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063588/bluetooth-headphones-connect-but-there-isnt-any-sound-ubuntu-18-04/1063595#1063595

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the correct device is already highlighted under *Settings > Sound > Output*, try selecting a different device then the desired device.

I'm having the same problem but couldn't find a workaround other than this.

Comment: a handy way to get to those sound settings is this gnome tweak . It puts a headphone icon in the top bar https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159915/playing-via-bluetooth

Comment: @pierrely could you check the link again? Which setting or extension are you referring to?

Comment: oops sorry, wrong link, this is it https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1271/sound-settings/