# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS --Bluetooth usb dongle and head set connected but no audio

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, headset

I have checked whether my bluetooth dongle is connected using

```
   one@one$ lsusb
   Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

[image: Bluetooth Manager shows]

I am able to see that the bluetooth device is connected but no audio, installed pulse audio volume control.

Used the script from another post
[Bluetooth Headphones connect but there isn't any sound. Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063588/bluetooth-headphones-connect-but-there-isnt-any-sound-ubuntu-18-04)

```
python3.6 a2dp.py 
Connection MADE
Selecting device:
1. 40:45:DA:76:64:0F 40-45-DA-76-64-0F
2. AC:5A:5E:55:61:D3 Bluetooth music
3. 30:23:D5:C4:EA:64 Krish series
Select device[1]:
3
Device MAC: 30:23:D5:C4:EA:64
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 15 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 14 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 13 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 12 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 11 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 10 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 9 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 8 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 7 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 6 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 5 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 4 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 3 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 2 more times
Cannot find `bluez_card.30_23_D5_C4_EA_64` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 1 more times
It seems device: 30:23:D5:C4:EA:64 is not connected yet, trying to connect.
Connecting again.
Expression "Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed" failed with fail pattern: "fail"
Exiting bluetoothctl
```